# Toggle width on hover, stay on click, release on click and click off

Tags: jquery, css, width, toggle

I have a div that expands on hover via CSS. I want it to stay at that width when the user click on the div. So far I have this working.

However I need the div to collapse back to original size when the user clicks the div again (toggle) and if the user clicks off the div on the rest of the document.

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfKYr/5/)

jQuery here:

```
$(".rail").click(function() {
    $(".rail").width( 180 );
});
```

CSS here:

```
.rail{
   width: 30px;
   border-left: 10px solid #ff5400;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 }
.rail:hover{
   width: 180px;
   background-color: #ddd;
   -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".rail").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    },
    click: function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.rail') && $('.rail').is('.active')) $('.rail').removeClass('active');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfKYr/6/)

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer. It's twice as complex. :\

Comment: @teh1 - Not really, I just did the hover stuff in jQuery as well, as I like to just have it all in one place, and if you remove the hover functionality, it's almost exactly the same as your answer.

Comment: That's very intrusive though. Taking out the jQuery will completely break it. With my method it will function entirely except for sticking expanded when clicking without the jQuery. No worries.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are. I updated that fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZfKYr/8/

What I changed was:

```
1.) Added a '.rail-sticky' rule that forces the rail open.
2.) Changed the click function to toggle that rule instead of forcing it open.
```

HTML:

```
<div class="rail">

</div>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".rail").click(function() {
    $(".rail").toggleClass('rail-sticky');
    return false;
});

$(document).on('click',':not(.rail)',function()
{
    $('.rail').removeClass('rail-sticky');
});
```

​

CSS:

```
.rail{
    width: 30px;
    border-left: 10px solid #ff5400;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.rail:hover{
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.rail-sticky
{
    width: 180px;
}​
```

Comment: Had to give it to adeneo for giving me the click off feature on the rest of the page.